# How do I edit embed message when clicking on a button?

Tags: c#, discord, discord.net

I've a message that is sent using

```
var msg = await Context.Guild.GetTextChannel(channelId)
                       .SendMessageAsync(embed: eb.Build(), components: components);
```

How do I record a message or its ID to change it by clicking a button if they are in different classes?

```
[ComponentInteraction("declineBtn")]
public async Task HandleButtonDecline()
{
  await msg.ModifyAsync(msg =>
  {
    msg.Embed = eb.Build();
    msg.Components = componentsDisable;
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```cs
[ComponentInteraction("declineBtn")]
public async Task HandleButtonDecline()
{
    var parsedArg = (SocketMessageComponent)Context.Interaction;
    // This will replace the current embed with `eb.Build()` embed
    parsedArg.UpdateAsync(msg => msg.Embeds = new Embed[] { eb.Build() });
}
```